# Windows server 2008 r2 console stuck at "waiting for user profile service"

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, login

I have a windows 2008 R2 server, running on dell poweredge t300.  Using hyper-v to run a windows 2008 R2 server also.

Suddenly, today, my virtual console (on the virtual copy of windows 2008 server r2) will not let me login as administrator. It starts to login but then sticks at the message:
   Please wait for the User profile Service

and is unresponsive to keypresses (incl ctrl-alt-del). The only way out is a crash.

It starts up in safe mode without networking ok but not in safe mode with networking.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

did you disabled IPV6?
http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/Windows_Server_2008/Q_26464594.html
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Server_Applications/Q_24110016.html
is this server multi-homed?

Comment: The server is mulkti-homed. Two IP interfaces, one for the host 9with an IP address0 and one as the virtual bridge to the VM. Both have IP v6 disabled I believe, though i cant get in to check.

Comment: IPv6 needs to be running. See if you can use the ipv6.exe command.

Comment: thanks guys - turning on ipv6 seems to have been the problem, it needs to be turned on in the host machine.

Comment: Enabling IPv6 worked for me also. Running Win 2k8 R2 VMware Virtual machine.